# Discord.py Embed Overriding How to fix it

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add another embed msg in my discord,py but it overrides the first one

````py
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Avengers Infinity War"))

embed=discord.Embed(title="Nothing! Just lurking :eyes:", color=0x00ffd5) ### <== 1
embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/795599610986627072.gif?v=1")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$What are you doing.?'):
       await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

    if message.content.startswith('$Hello'):
       await message.channel.send('Hi!')

    if message.content.startswith('$help'):
       await message.channel.send('```1)$help                                                               2)$Hello                                                                           3)$What are you doing.?```')

embed=discord.Embed(title="Assembling ", color=0x00ffd5) ### <== 2
embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/795596234210934817/795660131547086858/main-qimg-3b0c88bfea0119f0dcb6ebc0de1d5192.gif")
    if message.content.startswith('$Assemble'):
       await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
````

The gif (marked by `### <== 1`) gets replaced by `### <== 2`.

Comment: We can't see line numbers. Please add more details.

Comment: @Yatin the 1. gif gets replaced by 2

Comment: Please don't add "!!!!!!" to your question and provide clear details. See [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You created the first embed outside of on_message. As a result, you'll get a NameError if the message contains `$what are you doing.?` because the call to `send` that you have after that if statement tries to access a variable named `embed`, a variable that was defined outside of the function. You should define that embed in on_message. Also, you can't have two variables named the same thing, because one will overwrite the other. You might want to rename one of the variables named `embed` to something else.